# Reduce or curtailment a displayed cells text in Gridview without wrapping text

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have executed a database query that returns a long field data, in my case I need to curtailment one of this fields as the sample below.

[image]

How can I display a shortcuted content with add dots like(...)

Comment: you can reduce it in select query it self. like if length of data is exceed from certain limit than you can substring that content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below query

```
select (CASE WHEN LEN(Name)>20 THEN SUBSTRING(NAme,0,20) + '...' ELSE Name END) AS Name from Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("URL").ToString().Length > 20? (Eval("URL") as string).Substring(0,10) + " ..." : Eval("URL")  %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("URL") %> '> </asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Adjust the length as you wish.